# How to set a specific default directory for a Save As operation in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

We have a MS Access software which we need to be able to save a MS Word document from. It is not problem to get the save as dialog in word, using the VBA, but is it possible to get it to change the default directory to a path specified in the VBA? It just saves as on the desktop as default.

Edit: For the first answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Application.FileDialog to ask the user for a path to save to:

```
Dim ofd As Office.FileDialog
Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
ofd.Title = "Save As..."
ofd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
ofd.InitialFileName = "c:\temp\myfile"

' Show Dialog and abort if user clicks cancel:
If (ofd.Show = 0) Then Exit Sub

MsgBox ofd.SelectedItems(1) ' shows the selected filename
```

Use that path to directly save the word document.

Comment: Hi Oliver. You comment works just fine, but it saves as in access. Not the MS word document. How do i activate the word window and execute the same procedure?

Comment: If your code is running in Access, you cannot remote-control the Word Save-As Dialog. My example only returns the path that you can use to call .SaveAs() on your Word document.

Comment: Oh, okay, thats a shame. You cant think of any work around to get word to do it? We also need other programs to do so (Mathcad, SolidWorks, Ansys, Excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the filename you would like to the dialog as such:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename("c:\temp\myfile")
```

This will open the dialog in the temp folder and suggest myfile as name for the file.

See here for other modify-able stuff in the dialog: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Why did i get minus one?
No i can not use that command. It says that the command can not be used in word through access.

Comment: Application.GetSaveAsFilename() was new in Office 2010. If you are using 2007, it's not there.

Comment: @Emil: If your code is Access VBA code, "Application" will be the Access application. You will need a reference to the *Word* Application to issue GetSaveAsFilename (if it is even there, as Oliver indicates)

Comment: @bidabia: The availability of these functions via the Application object is sadly very inconsistent throughout the various Office Suite Applications. Excel had it for a very long time, while Access still doesn't. Its more consistent to use the FileDialog that the Office-Library provides, because you can use it via VBA in all Applications in the same way.

Comment: It is office 2010. It is not a problem to get VBA to activate MS Word and then the save as dialog. The only issue is to make it start in a specific folder. It is possible to do a save as in a folder if the filename is given... So it must be possible, since every similar tasks are... :S